# Ansible: Reboot if no user logged in (ansible.builtin.reboot)

Tags: ansible

We need to reboot a Linux server if nobody is logged in.

`ansible.builtin.reboot` doesn't seem to have an option to check for that.

Does Ansible have a way of checking if there are users logged in (kind of a `who` command)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `who` command

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Gather logged in user
    shell:
      cmd: who | cut -d " " -f 1
    register: result
    changed_when: false
    check_mode: false

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      var: result.stdout_lines
    when: result.stdout_lines | length > 1
```

and may check the return values as in the example given and perform further tasks like

```yaml
- name: Reboot if required
  reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 150
  when: reboot_allowed # or result.stdout_lines | length < 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out who is currently logged in you have a number of options in linux itself. On https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-logged-in-users/ you can find these commands:

```
w
who
users
finger
```

Use a shell module to run the command and count the lines. This could roughly look like this (I did not run these commands to check):

```
- name: count logged in users
  shell: "who | wc --lines"
  register: usercount

- name: reboot if noone is logged on
  command: /sbin/reboot
  when: "usercount.stdout < 2"
```